# Elastic search 2.0 migration: "inFilter" equivalent

Tags: elasticsearch

I am migrating from Elasticsearch version 1.4.2 to **2.x**.

Since there have been breaking changes in 2.x, and some of the APIs have been removed, my current code breaks.

I am looking for the equivalent of **`inFilter`** filters in version 2.x.

```
Client client = CerridSearchClientFactory.getInstance().getClient();
        SearchRequestBuilder requestBuilder1 = client.prepareSearch(<index name>);
                Double[] notNan = new Double[1];
                notNan[0] = Double.NaN;
                    FilterAggregationBuilder  filter = AggregationBuilders.filter(<filter name>).filter(FilterBuilders.notFilter(FilterBuilders.inFilter(<field name> , notNan)));
                 filter = filter.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.stats(<field name>)
                            .field(<field name>));
                SearchResponse  sr = requestBuilder.addAggregation(filter).execute().actionGet();
```

I performing stats aggregation with filter on it. I am also doing sum, min , max aggregation with filter aggregation with not in like query.

Comment: It would help if you include a concrete example of the 1.4 query you have, and include what you've tried to convert it to 2.x. Much will (or at least could) depend on the specifics.

Comment: I am performing a filter aggregations;  FilterBuilders.notFilter(FilterBuilders.inFilter(<fieldName> , notNan))); Where I am trying to include or exclude some of values.

Comment: Okay. But I'd just repeat my previous comment: we can help a lot better if you add a concrete example to your post.

Comment: I have modified the question with code example and use case detail.

Answer (score 0):

[inFilter](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13145) was just an alias for the terms filter.

As filters were removed, you should use the [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html).